# Button to turn on Do Not Disturb

Tags: do-not-disturb

I just switched from iOS to Android.  I bought a Samsung Galaxy S9+ and I am looking for a quick way to enable Do Not Disturb.  iOS has a simple button to enable DND.  However, I cant find a way to do this on my phone.  Everything I google, doesnt seem to apply to this phone or android version.

I tried [this](https://www.addictivetips.com/android/how-to-add-a-do-not-disturb-switch-to-the-volume-controls-in-android-7/), but it doesnt seem to apply to my phone.

Comment: This button is not a feature of Android. You can try [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cabooze.buzzoff) or similar apps from Play Store

Comment: When you say that IOS has a simple button to do so, are you talking about a physical button, or are you talking about an easily accessible setting? And isn't putting your sound to the lowest, equivalent to DND mode?

Comment: @aBochur im talking about an easily accessible setting.  In the latest iOS, you just simply swipe up from the bottom edge of the phone and there is a soft button to enable/disable DND.  On my S9+, I have to go into multiple menus to enable it.  Also, I tried putting the sound all the way down till it vibrates and then checked if DND was enabled at that point and it was not.

Comment: @Keltari swipe the notification panel with two fingers, and you should see a setting for that. If you do, let me know, and I'll post an answer with instructions on how to move it up. It was definitely there on s7. Not sure if they removed he since

Comment: @aBochur Its definitely not there. '

Comment: Do you have similar settings like [these](https://goo.gl/images/nd5gD6)? If you don't see that specific one, i guess they removed it. But to confirm, swipe right or left, to see if it's there

Comment: @aBochur Lol.  The settings menu does not have DND on the first screen.  I did not realize you can swipe to the right.  It is on the *NEXT* screen.  If you make your comment an answer, I will select it.  I guess now I need research to see if its possible to reorder that menu.

Comment: @Keltari no problem. I'll also advise on how to reorder

Comment: @aBochur I found how to reorder it.  just make your comment an answer and ill accept it.  :)  Thanks for the help.  While I am definitely liking Android over iOS, the configurability adds a lot of complexity.  Having to google how to do anything is tedious, granted you probably only need to do it once.

Comment: In the answer below, I assume that it's very similar to how it works on Galaxy s8. If that's not so, please let me know, as I don't have one to test this on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Do not Disturb setting is easily accessible in the notification panel on most Android devices.

To find it on a Galaxy S9+, using two fingers, swipe from the top of the screen, and you'll see all available quick settings. You should see DND mode as one of the option. (If it's not there, swipe the screen to the right or to the left to find it)

Tap on the DND setting to turn it on or off. Long press on it to enter more DND settings.

Below, is a screenshot of how this looks on a galaxy S8. it looks similar On an S9+
[image]

**How to move it to a more convenient place:**

To move the quick setting to a more convenient place like next to the WiFi setting, all you have to do, is press on the three dots (circled with green in the screenshot) and press on *button order* this will give you access to changing the order of the settings.

Answer (score 1):

Android 4.4. 
there is such a function. in the curtain. convenient, beautiful, functional.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This button doesnt exist on my phone.  Between WiFi and the volume button is WiFi calling, not DND

Comment: @Keltari check the other answer, the DnD button may no tbe in the same location, the curtain's buttons can be edited and customized. Άνδρας I do not know if "curtain" is the official keyword for swiping down, but I love this term and hope I remember to call it that.